# Table.getCell() not working on cell in newly inserted row

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I am trying to insert a new row to a table in Word and change the content of the cells in the new row. The problem that I am having is that after insertion of the row, the Word api is not able to find cells in the new row.
Below I added a very simplified version of my code.

```js
await Word.run(async(context) => {
    let table = context.document.body.tables.getFirstOrNullObject();
    context.load(table, {
        expand: "rows/items/cells/items/body"
    })
    await context.sync();

    let row = table.rows.items[table.rowCount - 1];
    row.insertRows("After", 1);
    await context.sync();

    let cell = table.getCell(2, 0); //throws "ItemNotFound" exception
    cell.body.insertText("test", "Replace");

    await context.sync();
});
```

Is there a way to get this working or is this a bug?

(please don't suggest using the values parameter on insert row as my actual code is much more complicated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is happening is that you haven't reloaded the `table` object. You need to tell the API to explicitly reload `table` before the `sync()` will pick up that request:

```ts
let row = table.rows.items[table.rowCount - 1];
row.insertRows("After", 1);
context.load(table, {expand: "rows/items/cells/items/body"});
await context.sync();
```

Another way to approach this would be to load just the row you've added rather than reloading the entire table. You can do this by loading the `tableRowCollection` returned by `insertRows()`:

```ts
let newRows = row.insertRows("After", 1);
context.load(newRows, { expand: "items/cells/items/body" });
await context.sync();
newRows.items[0].cells.items[0].body.insertText("test", "Replace");
```

Comment: I already tried this and did not fix the issue. Additional information is that I initially have a table of 2 rows and want to alter a cell in the last (new) row

Comment: Odd. I was able to replicate your bug in ScriptLab. Adding `context.load(table, {expand: "rows/items/cells/items/body"});` prior to calling `sync()` solved it. Did you get the same error after adding that line?

Comment: Yes, but when I have more than 2 rows in my initial table in my document then it works fine. I did some additional testing and your second suggestion works for me (loading the newly added row). Loading the entire table and trying to get a cell of the newly added row from table level is not working.